Redirect blog.liquid.diamonds to liquid.diamonds/blog along with all the nested URLs
I had a wordpress blog hosted at https://blog.liquid.diamonds. I have now migrated to liquid.diamonds/blog and all the associated pages. Webflow is used for maintaining liquid.diamonds and the blog as a subdirectory.
How can I support / redirect my old URLs at blog.liquid.diamonds to liquid.diamonds/blog including nested URLs

https://blog.liquid.diamonds/category/liquidity/
https://blog.liquid.diamonds/author/liquidmark/
https://blog.liquid.diamonds/tag/diamond-data/

Using the wordpress redirection plugin, I have redirected requests to blog.liquid.diamonds to liquid.diamonds/blog but other URLs don't redirect. See below screenshot for the details
